# Unable to open PDF while converting it from a HTML in react

Tags: reactjs

I am getting an html file from a backend application and now saving it in pdf format in react. However, unable to open it in adobe :(

```
  CreateFile(data, contentType) {
    let file;

    if (contentType === "text/html") {
       // file = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
        file = new Blob([new Uint8Array(data)], { type: contentType });
    } 



   saveDocument() {
    let contentType = "application/pdf";
    let file = this.createFile(data,
```

contentType.toLowerCase());

```
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) // IE10+
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, filename);
    else { // others apart from Safari and Opera mini
        var a = document.createElement("a"),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using a library like wkhtmltopdf in your backend to convert the html into pdf before sending it.